# Not found error in Get /create action in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on creating a simple bulletin board with mysql and node.js.

I am using an express-generator and I want to write in index.js via routing and create.ejs in views.js.

My create.ejs has a form that passes input values ​​to post.

However, if you access `/create`, a Not Found (404 Error) occurs.

**routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mysql = require("mysql");

var client = mysql.createConnection({
  user: "root",
  password: "ps",
  database: "mysqlTest"
})

router.get('/create', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('create');
});

router.post('/create', function(req, res, next) {
  var body = req.body;

  client.query("INSERT INTO products (name, modelnumber, series) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [
      body.name, body.modelnumber, body.series
    ], function(){
    res.redirect("/create");
  });
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  client.query("SELECT * FROM products;", function(err, result, fields){
    if(err){
      console.log("There is an error in the query statement.");
    }
    else{
      res.json(result);
    }
  });

});
module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what HTTP method is failing for you. Which URL/method is getting the unexpected 404? Seeing the form might help us.

Comment: Ah, I think some punctuation made things weird. Is it the `GET /create` that's failing?

Comment: That's right. I get a 404 error in Get /create

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Upon quick glance I found the following items that may be incorrect

First,

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
```

NodeJS by default uses a file named index.js by default, so you can just specify the line like so

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/'); //This is a recommended practice.
```

Second, in your lines
`router.get('/create'... and router.post('/create', ...` you have a slash in the name.

However, since you are wiring this to the route in the following line:

```
app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

You can get rid of the slashes in the create endpoint. It should look more like this:

`router.get('create'... and router.post('create', ...`

I think this will do it.
If not, I can run it through a debugger if you provide a package.json.

Comment: `/` is called a slash. `\\` is a backslash.